# Hovering the text for full form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

When I mouse hover the text below the cube,
I need to display a small window with a text in it.
I got the text from js but not sure how to integrate with hover function.
Can you tell me how to implement it?
Providing my code below;
when I hover over CRM it should show Customer Relationship Management.

The hover functionality working fine when I hover over the text box,
but I don't know how to get the text below the cube.
I have included `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` functions,
but I don't know how to achieve for the text below the cube.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('.cubeCell').each(function () {
            var htmlText = $(this).attr('data-text');
            $(this).append('<div class="cubeTextStyle">' + htmlText + '</div>');
        });
    }, 600);
});

<script type="text/javascript">
                function showStock(ii) {
                    var sh = $(ii).parent().find($('.divStock'));
                    var sharrow = $(ii).parent().find($('.stockarrow'));
                    sh.show();
                    sharrow.show();

                }
                /**
                 * hide stock
                 */
                function hideStock(ii) {
                    var shs = $(ii).parent().find($('.divStock'));
                    var sharrows = $(ii).parent().find($('.stockarrow'));
                    shs.hide();
                    sharrows.hide();
                }
                </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cubeCell" data-text="CRM" class="desktopContactImage cubeCell"
                      data-caption="&lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 14px; color: grey;' href='/Inventory/Partnumber/?ps=list' &gt;Register&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 14px; color: grey;' href='/Bom/Bom/?ps=list' &gt;Demo&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 14px; color: grey;' &gt;Reports&lt;/a&gt;"
                      data-image="http://intra.defie.co/images/Desktop_icons_02.07.13/guest.png"></div>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not formed correctly.  Follow jsfiddle recommendations and strip unneeded elements (javascript includes, css includes, etc).

Comment: Too see what Lowkase is referring to, click the TidyUp button.

Comment: You don't need `window.setTimeout(function() {`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at using custom content in the jQuery UI Tooltip widget: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content

Comment: @all: i updated the fiddle can you guys help me with that

Comment: Would you even need to use javascript for the hiding?  
:hover with visibility:hidden might do the trick.

Comment: @EdgarAllanPwn: how to implement hover on this code $('document').ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('.cubeCell').each(function () {
            var htmlText = $(this).attr('data-text');
            $(this).append('<div class="cubeTextStyle">' + htmlText + '</div>');
        });
    }, 600);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First please don't provide Fiddles like that..ever, separate the different languages into their relevant boxes and use the resources tabs to link to files. It maks things a lot clearer for us to help.

Second don't include code that's not relevant, for example the the google analytic script, yes it will take more time for you to format the fiddle to use as an example but you'll get a quicker response.

If you simply need to hover over CSM and have "Customer Relationship Management" appear underneath it then you can do something like the below.

```
$('.cubeTextStyle').hover(
   function(){
      $(this).append('<span>Customer Relationship Management</span>');
   },
   function(){
      $('.cubeTextStyle span').remove();
   }
);
```

I haven't used your fiddle because I won't sift through all of your code, but please see this [new basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vACa7/).