# Pop-up to make it centre

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

When I click the sign up button the popup opens up.
It works fine in the desktop but when I reduce the browser window the pop up moves to the left hand corner of the browser.
How to make the pop up to center on an iPhone?
How to fix it?

Providing my code below:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="signup-modal">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h1>Sign up </h1>
    <form method="POST" autocomplete="off" id="id_registerForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="usertype" value="3" readonly />
        <fieldset>      
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="fullname" maxlength="30" required="required" id="id_username" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Company" name="company" maxlength="30" required="required" id="id_company" />       
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" maxlength="75" required="required" id="id_email" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required="required" id="id_password" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" name="repassword" required="required" id="id_repassword" />
        <textarea name="inquiry" placeholder="Inquiry" rows="3" required="required" id="id_inquiryForm" style="width:290px;"></textarea>
        <input id="id_signUp" type="button" value="Sign Up" class="btn">
        </fieldset>
        <!-- <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><span>Already have an account?</span> Log in</a> -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide relevant javascript and CSS.

Comment: Please remove all code not needed to reproduce the problem; then add the definition of the classes you use. Otherwise it's really hard to answer your question!

Comment: Apply "margin:auto;" to "myModal"div element on query @media (max-width: 767px)
alredy tested on your page with chrome dev tools...

Answer (score 0):

you will need diferent styles for your modal window

I use this in my roject

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
   /* my styles goes here */
}
```

now you have this styles for modal:

```
#signup-modal, #login-modal {
width: 300px;
padding: 0 40px;
background: #fff;
border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
margin-left: -190px;
border-radius: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 40px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset;
margin-top: -306px;}
```

that's why it goes out of the window, you have to write other `styles` for `smaller screens`.

I tried to remove the `margins` and set it to `margin: auto`, I did it in inspect element in chrome and it didn't worked well when resizing, but could work if you'll do it on your local machine, try this too. If not, go for @media screen.

here is a good link on this

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been focused on by using `@media-screen` but as you tagged jQuery in the question, thought I would give an alternative solution. Might be a bit OTT for what you're after ... but hey I like it and it works. Plus it saves having to add several media queries for screen sizes.

```
var sBox = $('#signup-modal');
var uPos = function(){
   //Get sign-up box height and width
   sBoxHeight = parseInt(sBox.css('height'));
   sBoxWidth = parseInt(sBox.css('width'));

   //Get window height and width
   wHeight = window.innerHeight;
   wWidth = window.innerWidth;

   //Work out the position for the sign-up box
   sBoxTop = (wHeight/2) - (sBoxHeight/2);
   sBoxLeft = (wWidth/2) - (sBoxWidth/2);

   //Apply to the sign-up box
   sBox.css({
      margin:'0px',
      left:sBoxLeft - 55,
      top:sBoxTop
   });
}

//Apply on page load
uPos();

//Apply when window is resized
$(window).resize(function(){
   uPos();
});
```

Comment: can you share your fiddle link

Comment: @user2045025 I didn't do this in Fiddle but tried it live on your site, simply copy the whole on my script into your web console and it will work and override all of your css styling. Give me 2 minutes and I'll put into a fiddle

Comment: thank you can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370619/hovering-the-text-for-full-form?noredirect=1#comment21721833_15370619